# Do Eclipse workspaces depend on a specific Eclipse version?

Tags: java, eclipse

Perhaps a newbie question, but I could not find an answer on this one.

**Question: Do Eclipse workspaces depend on a specific Eclipse version (and analgously: do Eclipse projects depend on a specific Eclipse version)?**

For Example, on a workspace created with Eclipse 3.x, should I only work with Eclipse 3.x or can I also work on this workspace with Eclipse 4.x.

Comment: following post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868848/2-eclipse-versions-with-same-workspace

Comment: Ideally there shouldn't be an issue, but from my experience there is a good chance that you might run into something. I haven't come across any issues that was tough to resolve though..

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it depends.

It depends on the plug-ins you're using, on how well they've each been written to deal with this case, and how prone they are to migrating metadata without your consent rather than simply using what's there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it depends. See this link [Plugin Migration Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/nav/2_3).
Here you find some guidelines to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a chance of something happening, so it's a good idea to back up your workspace in case you need to fall back to an older version of eclipse. However, in most cases you shouldn't have an issue, provided you don't have your workspace inside your Eclipse installation directory. You can find more information about upgrading and workspaces from help.eclipse.org:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-2.htm

Hope this helps.